# How to call wcf webserice method from codeigniter?

Tags: php, json, wcf, codeigniter

Any one help me
How to call WCF Webservice (http://subdomain.mydomain.org/mywcfservice/mywcfservice.svc) method (mymethod) from codeigniter framework
i used this code

```
try{ 
    $client = new 
        SoapClient( 
            "http://subdomain.mydomain.org/mywcfservice/mywcfservice.svc" 
        );
    $params = array('UserId'=>"1", 'UserAuth'=>"123456"); 
    $webService = $client->GetData($params); 
    $wsResult = $webService->Data; 
    print  $wsResult; 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    print  'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n"; 
}
```

but i have this error

```
Caught exception: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find in 'http://subdomain.mydomain.org/mywcfservice/mywcfservice.svc'
```

knowing that this method returns JSON Object (myjsonobject) which i want to parse it also

thanks for helping

Comment: try adding `?wsdl` to the end of the domain